# How to add left border in a Row/Column/Card Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to add a left/start vertical border to view (Column), Not able to get the solution. as of now was trying to achieve using a divider inside the column it also need a height, but it depends on the contents inside the column, sometime it may grow.

```
 Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 34.dp)) {
                Divider(
                    color = Color.Red,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .height(100.dp)
                        .padding(end = 34.dp).width(2.dp)
                )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the **`drawWithCache`** modifier using the **`drawLine`** function.

Something like:

```
Column(modifier =
    Modifier
        .padding(start = 34.dp)
        .size(100.dp, 75.dp)
        .drawWithCache {
            onDrawWithContent {

                // draw behind the content the vertical line on the left
                drawLine(
                    color = Color.Red, 
                    start = Offset.Zero, 
                    end = Offset(0f, this.size.height),
                    strokeWidth= 1f
                )

                // draw the content
                drawContent()
            }
        }
){
    //...content
}
```

[image]

If you want to use a **`Divider`** you can use `fillMaxHeight()` applying an [**intrinsic measurements**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/intrinsic-measurements) to its parent container.

Something like:

```
Row(modifier = Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)) {

    Divider(
        color = Color.Red,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()  //important
            .width(2.dp)
    )
     
   Box(Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(100.dp).background(Yellow))
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can achive this with `Modifier.drawBehind` and `drawLine`

**Code**

```
        TextButton(
            onClick = {
                //Click Functions
            },
            modifier = Modifier.drawBehind {
                val strokeWidth = 1 * density
                //Draw line function for left border
                drawLine(
                    Color.LightGray,
                    Offset(0f, strokeWidth),
                    Offset(0f, size.height),
                    strokeWidth
                )
            }
        )
        {
            Text("Left Border")
        }
```

**Output**

[image: OutoutImage]